# How to add a self-signed certificate to the trusted store on S3 bucket(static website)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a static website on AWS S3 and it requests various APIs of a backend server which has a self signed certificate. The static website is HTTPS enabled with AWS certificate and running using cloudfront.

I want to enable this connection of real SSL certificate with my self signed certificate backend.

So is it possible to store this self signed certificate as a trusted certificate for S3 static website server?

Answer (score 1):

There is no trusted certificate store in an S3 bucket. S3 just stores your website files, it doesn't run the actual website code. When a person visits your website, their web browser downloads the files from S3/CloudFront, and then executes your website inside the local web browser.

You would have to add your self-signed certificate to the trusted store of each visitor's computer. Unless you only have a few users, and you have administrator access to their laptops, the better solution is to use a real SSL certificate on your server.